# from imei number how to find latitude and longitude in android 4.0.3?

Tags: android, imei

In android 4.0.3 i find phone's imei number.But using that number im not able to **find latitude longitude**..plzz suggest me.

Comment: are you trying to deduct location based on the phones IMEI?

Comment: What is the connection between IMEI and position?

Comment: @Hardi Shah.. IMEI has nothing to do Location (Atleast for developer).. you should do that using **Network or GPS**

Comment: Yes im trying to find the location.ya but i dont want to use GPS based location service.

Comment: Then go for Network service provider or IP based

Comment: read the following code [android location provider's](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#StartListening)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot recognize your lat and lang based on your IMEI number, you can only get them from either your GPS, network service provider or your IP..

Answer (score 1):

IMEI is a global unique number which  used to identify your phone, but not possible for location.

I believe what you're looking for is "Cell ID" but not IMEI.

> A CellID is the unique number of a GSM cell for a given operator. 
>       Your phone is always connected to a Cell, and by knowing this number, 
>       you know the Cell. By knowing the position of the cell, you know where you are.

There's a free cell id database here, you could use their library to get the position by Cell ID.

[OpenCellID website](http://opencellid.org/)